# How do I find relavence documents against the query

Tags: java, list, arraylist, vector, tf-idf

I going through a project where I have to find the relevant document one by one against the query. First I calculated the **TF, IDF** for all the words of all documents. And then I multiplied the TF and IDF and store each term and its corresponding TF-IDF score for a particular document inside a List.here the class named Tfidf calculating TF and IDF

```
public double TF(String[] document, String term) {
    double value = 0;                 //calculate Term Frequency for all term
    for (String s : document) {
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(term)) {
            tfmap.put(s, tfmap.getOrDefault(term, 0) + 1);
            for (Map.Entry entry : tfmap.entrySet()) {
                value = (int) entry.getValue();
            }
        }
    }
    return value / document.length;
}

public double idf(List alldocument, String term) {
    double b = alldocument.size();
    double count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < alldocument.size(); i++) {
        String[] f = alldocument.get(i).toString().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", " ").trim().replaceAll(" +", " ").toLowerCase().split(" ");

        for (String ss : f) {
            if (ss.equalsIgnoreCase(term)) {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1 + Math.log(b / count);
}}
```

here the code where I multiplied the TF and IDF

```
  List<String> alldocument= new ArrayList<>();
  List tfidfVector = new ArrayList<>();
 public void TfIdf() {
    double tf;
    double idf;
    double tfidf = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < alldocument.size(); i++) {
        double[] tfidfvector = new double[allterm.size()];  //allterm is all unique word in all documents
        for (String terms : allterm) {
            String[] file = alldocument.get(i).replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", " ").trim().replaceAll(" +", " ").toLowerCase().split(" ");
            int count = 0;
            tf = new Tfidf().TF(file, terms);
            idf = new Tfidf().idf(alldocument, terms);
            tfidf = tf * idf;
            tfidfvector[count] = tfidf;
            count++;
        }
        tfidfVector.add(tfidfvector);            
    }   
}
```

can anyone tell me how I Compute the TF-IDF vector for the query If my query is "**life and learning**"?and how can I calculate the cosine similarity of the query between all the Documents to find the similarity between the query and all the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tf-idf score is used in conjunction with the cosine similarity between the query and a document.  So you need to compute a dot product between two vectors. One vector represents the query "life and learning". The other vector represents one of the documents. To find the most relevant document, you need to calculate the cosine similarity with all of the documents (or ideally, only the ones that contain some of the words).
In the vector space model, each dimension of the vector represents one distinct word. So in this particular example, the only two relevant dimensions would be those representing "life", "and", "learning". Theoretically there are other dimensions corresponding to every other known word, but the score of those will be 0 in this case so they can be skipped over when calculating the cosine similarity.

There are several possible variations of exactly how to apply the weighting. But if we stick to the simplest...
You can consider the query vector to have <life:1, and:1 learning: 1>. And the document vector to have <word1: tf_word1/idf_word1, word2: tf_word2/idf_word2, ..., wordN: tf_wordN/idf_wordN>.
Then you just compute the dot product between these two vectors.  For words not appearing in the query, you're just going to end up multiplying by 0 and adding it to the score, which means you can ignore all those words. So you only need to consider the terms in the query. For each term in the query, multiply the tf in the query (or even just 1 if desired) by the tf-idf score of that term in the document.

There are many possible weighting variations you can use. You've already talked about TF and IDF. I also see you've written some code to normalize the term frequency by the length of the document, which is also. To learn more, you can refer to this section of the Introduction to Information Retrieval Textbook: https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/document-and-query-weighting-schemes-1.html#sec:querydocweighting. (Although, it might be too dense without reading some of the earlier sections)

FYI, sepcifically regarding the code you've posted, you're currently storing them in an ArrayList, just indexed in order. Well, you have an issue where count is being reset to 0 every time through the loop, which doesn't seem right. But ignoring that, you will want an easy way to look up the tf-idf information for a specific term. A HashTable is more natural for that than an ArrayList.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. should I calculate tfidf score for all terms of the documents or only the terms which have into the query?And how can I calculate Idf score for the query? 
 **Theoretically there are other dimensions corresponding to every other known word, but the score of those will be 0 in this case so they can be skipped over when calculating the cosine similarity**  what do u mean by this line?

Comment: You can pre-calculate TF and IDF for all terms in all documents. When you get a query, you look them up for only the terms in the query.

It depends on exactly what weighting scheme you want or have been asked for, but it would be very reasonable to only include idf as a factor once. Either in the query, or in the document, but not both. (This would be the easiest for what you've posted). If you specifically want or need idf weighting in both, you would lookup by term the idf score for each of the query terms (using a HashTable or equivalent that you've pre-computed).

Comment: That line means that when you calculate the cosine similarity, part of the dot product includes checking how the term frequencies of the words "apple", "banana", "cherry" etc. compare. To compute the dot product, you multiply the value of vector 1 with the corresponding value of vector 2, then sum them all up. The term frequency of "apple" in your sample query is 0.  Regardless of how many times the document has it, 0 * anything = 0. Then you add that 0 * anything to your summations, but adding 0 doesn't change your sum.

Comment: I can't understand properly what u said. I want to know when I calculate cosine similarity should I need to consider all words of the document? or only the word which has only the query if I only calculate the TF-IDF score only the queries three words?could u pls tell me step by step procedure?pls don't mind if I ask any silly question.

Comment: Just score the 3 words in the query.